# How to get background cell color in XSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.9 in my project I need  to get XSSF file cell background color.

```
Workbook myWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(filePath));
Sheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
Row currentRow = null;
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext())
{
currentRow = (Row) rowIterator.next();
totalColumns = currentRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

for (int column = 0; column < totalColumns; column++)
{
Cell cell = currentRow.getCell(column);
CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
short colorIdx=cellStyle.getFillForegroundColor();
// I am struct in this step  to get XSSF  cell background color

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In binary `BIFF` (`*.xls`) format (`HSSF` in `apache poi`), colors can only be indexed colors from the color palette.

But in `Office Open XML` (`*.xlsx`) format (`XSSF` in `apache poi`), colors can also be given in `RGB` form. So in `XSSF` not all colors will be indexed colors. That's why [CellStyle.getFillForegroundColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getFillForegroundColor--) returns 0 if the fill foreground color (the color of the fill pattern) is not an indexed color.

Do using [CellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getFillForegroundColorColor--) in `XSSF`. This returns a [Color](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Color.html) which is a [XSSFColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html) in `XSSF`.